# Selenium and Chromium on AWS-MWAA

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, chromium, mwaa

I'm currently using AWS Apache Airflow service (MWAA) and I've been needing to run some web **scraping** code using selenium, I did manage to add "chromedriver" and "selenium" to the dependencies of the project, but I've been struggling to add chromium to it (or any headless web browser).

AWS only allows a requirements.txt as dependencies to be installed using pip for MWAA, therefore I can't just add a "sudo yum install -y chromium" to the building cycle. I would like to know if it would be possible to add a chromedriver to the environment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what did you end up doing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can include the **webdriver-manager** in your requirements.txt as described [here](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/). This package will automate the download and setup of your chromium driver.

Then you can use selenium with chromium:

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromiumService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromiumService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()))
```